# How to send EKS (fargate)container logs to cloud watch using fluent bit?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, fluent-bit

I have going through documentation https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/fluent-bit-for-amazon-eks-on-aws-fargate-is-here/ and implementing it. But looks like it is not working.

1. I have created IAM policy & attached to Pod execution (cluster default iam role).
2. created those configmap in aws-obervability namespace.
   Still I'm not able to see any log group created in AWS.

Could you please help where I'm missing.

Answer (score 2):

Had similar issue using latest C plugin ([cloudwatch_logs](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/outputs/cloudwatch)) adding either `log_stream_prefix` or `log_stream_name` solved it.